# Purpose of Azure Management Certificates

Tags: azure, azure-management

I'm doing some testing with a new Cloud Service and for some reason in my certificates I'm getting a bunch of these entries

DC=Windows Azure Service Management for Extensions

All have different thumbprints. Doesn't seem to be affecting anything.. but annoying to have in the list.

What are they? How do I stop them from auto populating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things you could do through Azure Management Portal (like creating Cloud Services etc.) can essentially be done through [`Azure Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx). Management certificates are one way of authenticating your Service Management API requests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert.

There are many reasons that these certificates are created automatically. Some of them are:

- Whenever you download a publish setting file, a new management certificate is created.
- If you try to connect to your cloud service VM via RDP through portal, if you don't pay attention, a new certificate is created for RDP. I'm not 100% sure but same thing happens when you update Azure Diagnostics as diagnostics is again an extension.